# How do I calculate mean and sd with only such information provided?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIQd5.png)

If =+0.25 and  and  are independent random variables that are formulated to be normally distributed with ∼(,) and ∼(,),
(a) What is the mean and standard deviation of ? (refer to image)

Can someone explain to me how to approach this question with so little information given.

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Answer (score -1):

$E[Z]=E[X+0.25Y]=E[X]+0.25E[Y]=\mu_X+0.25\mu_Y$

$Var[Z]=Var[X+0.25Y]=Var[X]+Var[0.25Y]=Var[X]+(0.25)^2Var[Y]=\sigma_X^2+0.0625\sigma_Y^2$

In the expectation calculation we use the linearity of $E$.

In the variance calculation we use $Var[A+B]=Var[A]+Var[B]+2Cov[A,B]$ for r.v's A and B then independence to conclude $Cov[A,B]=0$. We also use $Var[kA]=k^2Var[A]$ for constant $k$.

Comment: What is the value of E[Z] then in this question? No other data was provided

Comment: $E[Z]=\mu_X+0.25\mu_Y$ and $Var[Z]=\sigma_X^2+0.0625\sigma_Y^2$, as shown.

Comment: the mean is 0.5 and the sd is 0.1 which i dont know how to get

Comment: What are $\mu_X, \mu_,\sigma_X, \sigma_Y$? If you know those then you simply substitute those values into the expressions for $E[Z]$ and $Var[Z]$.

Comment: Why was the answer downvoted?